# Extracting Month and Year from a string with Python Regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string from which I want to extract month name and year with Python regex. The string looks like the following-

```
x='januray valo na Feb 2017 valo Jan-2015 anj 1900 puch Janu Feb Jan Mar 15 MMMay-85 anF 15'
```

I code should return the following-

```
['Feb 2017', 'Jan-2015', 'Mar 15', 'May-85']
```

I have tried-

```
re.findall('[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec]{3}[\s-]\d{2,4}', x)
```

But I the code picking up **anF 15** as well, i.e. I am getting the following output-

```
['Feb 2017', 'Jan-2015', 'Mar 15', 'May-85', 'anF 15']
```

How can I stop the code from picking up wroong combinations like J**an|Fe**b?

Answer (score 4):

Use an alternation for the abbreviated month names.  That is, use the following regex pattern:

```
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[\s-]\d{2,4}
```

This says what you intend, namely to match one of 12 abbreviated month names, followed by a space/dash, then 2 or 4 digits.

```
x = 'januray valo na Feb 2017 valo Jan-2015 anj 1900 puch Janu Feb Jan Mar 15 MMMay-85 anF 15'

results = re.findall('(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[\s-]\d{2,4}', x)
print(results)

['Feb 2017', 'Jan-2015', 'Mar 15', 'May-85']
```

The problem with your current pattern is that it using a *character class*:

```
[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec]{3}[\s-]\d{2,4}
```

This actually says to match three *letters* from the letters contained by the month names (plus pipe).  Put another way, you are saying this:

```
[abceglnoprtuvyADFJMNOS|]{3}[\s-]\d{2,4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) here `[Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec]{3}`, which means any character from the character collection with repetition 3(`{3}`). In order to fix it use a [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead.

```
re.findall('(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[\s-]\d{2,4}', x)
```

Answer (score 1):

/[a-z]{3}.?\d{4}/gi

this will work
check [here](https://regex101.com/r/kJtPun/1)